# Delete two tables from a variable table in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to be able to use a varable table to delete records from two different tables.

I have this so far

```
declare @deleted TABLE (Card int)

insert into @deleted
select Card from table1
where recordstatus = 4

delete from table2
from @deleted d
where table2.actionstring like d.card
and Select convert(varchar(8),today,112)
from(Select dateadd(year,-1,getdate())as today)aa
```

sorry if this is confusing, I am using sql managment 2005
I basically want to be able to get a card number from table one, check to see if the date in table 2 is greater than a year if so delete the record in table 1.

In table two I do not have a field for card number so I need a LIKE statement.

I only have a error in the second part which reads,-
    from @deleted d

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the structure of `table2` ?? WHat fields do you have, what datatypes are they?? What kind of data is inside them?? You cannot do a `LIKE Card` if `Card` is an `INT` column.... what are you trying to match here??

Comment: Could you please just post the **table structure** for `table2` ?? Would be extremely helpful....

Comment: Does `table2` have an `ID` column? Or what is the key column(s) in `table2`?

Comment: It dosn't im afaid its basically a table that records history,

Comment: To sum up, you have some `Cards` in `table1` that have `recordstatus=4`. You need to check their history in `table2`: if it's older than 1 year, then you delete from `table2` the history records and... you delete from `table1` only those cards whose history you've deleted? or you delete all of `recordstatus=4` cards from `table1` anyway?

Comment: yes that is correct I look for records in table 1 with record status of 4, look in table 2 to see if it older than a year if so I delete both the record in table 1 and 2, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second part of the statement is quite confusing indeed.... you're mixing the DELETE with SELECT in a WHERE clause..... **what** exactly are you trying to achieve here??

```
declare @deleted TABLE (Card int)

insert into @deleted
  select Card from table1
  where recordstatus = 4

delete table2
from @deleted d
where table2.actionstring LIKE '%' + CAST(d.card AS VARCHAR(20)) + '%'
and CONVERT(DATETIME, table2.Date, 112) <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())

delete table1
from @deleted d
where table1.card = d.card
and CONVERT(DATETIME, table1.Date, 112) <= DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE())
```

So are you trying to delete all rows from `table2` where the the `Table2.ActionString` is equal to the `Card` column in your `@deleted` table?? Not quite clear.

Also : what's with the date constraint?? What field in `table2` do you want to check against?? What is the condition  - `<=` or `>=` or what?

Comment: well I put the date constraint on two lines but the date is in format yyyymmdd. I am trying to delete all rows in table 1 that have a record status of 4 and been there for over a year, I thought i could achieve this by,checking that particluar record againt table 2 to ensure that it has been there for a year and then delete it from table 1. Thank you for your time

Comment: @Leigh: updated my answer, hopefully I understand what you're really trying to do......

Comment: thanks marc however the action string not only contains the card number but other things as well, then i need to say if ture delete the record form table 1, sorry its confusing, thanks

Comment: @Leigh: can you show an example of what the "ActionString" looks like??

Comment: Edward Golding (07889955)changed photo

Comment: @Leigh: and that number in brackets would be the "Card" value from your temporary table?? Updated my answer yet again

Comment: @Leigh: Does `Card` have a fixed number of digits in `actionstring` (like 8 in your example)? In other words, could it be `...(000123)...`? Or it would necessarily be padded to become `00000123`?

Comment: @marc_s: I think it's only a matter of padding `d.card` accordingly before putting it to the `LIKE` operator.

Comment: Marc that worked, thank you so much, you will hate me but once the record is over a year old i need to also delete it from table 1. I do appreciate the time you have given to me, thanks#

Comment: @Leigh: updated my answer yet again - with a second statement to delete `table1` -- you might need to tweak that second DELETE statement a bit....

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE table1
FROM table1 INNER JOIN 
     table2 ON table1.card = table2.actionstring
WHERE table1.recordstatus = 4 AND
      table2.SomeDateColumn >= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Comment: won't work, as Leigh says - `card` is not equal to `actionstring`

Comment: you're right if both are not equal it won't work. Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
delete t1
from
   table1 t1
   join table2 t2
      on t2.actionstring like t1.card + '%'
      and [... other criteria ...]
```

Comment: `like t1.card + '%'` this won't work - you cannot concatenate an `INT` (`t1.card`) with a string literal....

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `table2` doesn't have a key complicates things a bit. In particular I cannot see how to avoid repeating the search in `table2` in this case.

Anyway, here goes:

```
DECLARE @deleted TABLE (card int);

/* store cards that are actually going to be deleted */
INSERT INTO @deleted (card)
SELECT DISTINCT t1.card
FROM table1 t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Date <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
    AND t2.actionstring LIKE '%' + RIGHT(100000000 + t1.card, 8) + '%'
WHERE t1.recordstatus = 4

/* delete the history for the selected cards */
DELETE FROM t2
FROM @deleted t1
  INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.Date <= DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
    AND t2.actionstring LIKE '%' + RIGHT(100000000 + t1.card, 8) + '%'

/* delete the cards from table1 */
DELETE FROM table1
FROM @deleted d
WHERE table1.card = d.card
  AND table1.recordstatus = 4  /* not sure if this condition is needed again
                                  but it will certainly do no harm */
```